# How to compare variables containing double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, string-comparison

I am trying:

```
FOO='Hi" a/b/c:'
BAR='hello'

if [ "$FOO" == "$BAR" ] ; then
  echo "yes"
fi
```

However what I get is an error because of what comes after the " in $FOO.
How can I escape the " in a variable? Or otherwise force bash to really compare the variables as is?

Comment: Can't reproduce. What's the error, *exactly*?

Comment: Are you using `if [ $FOO == $BAR ];` in your real code?

Comment: Do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top? If not, what is your shell? It might not be bash.

Answer (score 3):

You are not running the script under `bash`.  Bash would accept that non-standard syntax.  Other shells may reject.  For example, compare bash and dash:

```
$ bash script.sh 
$ dash script.sh 
script.sh: 4: [: Hi" a/b/c:: unexpected operator
```

As shown here, your script works under bash but not dash.  The problem is the *unexpected operator*.  That is referring to the `==` which is non-POSIX.  The solutions are either (a) run it under bash, or (b) replace:

```
if [ "$FOO" == "$BAR" ] ; then
```

with:

```
if [ "$FOO" = "$BAR" ] ; then
```

Inside `[...]`, the symbol `=` is the standard symbol to use for string equality.